# How to handle AWS Amplify Web App Security to protect user pool ID?

Tags: aws-amplify

I have an amplify config and instantiated Amplify in my client. If I directly access main.js in my browser, my user pool ID, password policy are being exposed to user. Is there any way I can hide amplify configuration being exposed to user?